# Is it possible to get static backreference with grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

I try to match a a group twice in multiline.

```
grep -Pz 'Source: (?<group>.*/).*\n.*\n.*\n.*\k<group>|$'
```

it work except one major problem - it doesn't, `\k<group>` search for `.*/` and not for the same characters that the first occurrence of group matched, which is normal considering that backreferencing is dynamic.

Is it possible to get «static» backreference, meaning that if `(?<test>\d\d)` match 45 , the next call to group test will **always** look for 45?

I'm not really good at explaining technical terms in english so feel free to yell at me or simply tell me to be more specific.

(I use perl grep here but if you have a solution who doesn't use it, go ahead)

Edit:

To answer the comment below:
1: I have a script that bulk move a lot of images files depending of ex if data. It works flawlessly but I want to test if in some cases the source Dir is the same as the output Dir.

A sample of a move:

`[1/1] (TEST - no files are being moved/copied)

Source: /disk/media/Camera/IMG_20130611_183722.jpg

Date/Time: 2013-06-11 16:37:23

Corresponding Tags: Composite:GPSDateTime

Destination (move): ./2013/06-Jun/20130611_163723.IMG_20130611_183722.jpg`

Here the input and output are not the same so I want the script to not detect anything but if

```
Source: /disk/media/Camera/IMG_20130611_183722.jpg
```

Goes to

```
Destination (move): /disk/media/Camera/20130611_163723.IMG_20130611_183722.jpg
```

I want to highlight the four lines.
The purpose is not to retrieve the data for anything else but just to visually identify quickly the detected files.

With the regexp up there it always highlight since the second occurrence of the group is dynamic (for grep it doesn't matter that the both are not identical)

Comment: Can you please (1) explain (_in the question_, not as a comment!) better what you are trying to accomplish, and post (2) a sample input, where the above command does something close to that you want, (3) the output you want, and (4) the output you're getting?

Comment: When I run your command on your data, I get the entire file. What are you getting?

Comment: Yes that the purpose of the |$ at the end. All the file are displayed but only the matched part are highlighted

Comment: Oh, you want the entire input file displayed, but you have `grep` aliased to `grep --color`, and you want the groups of four lines that match your regex to be highlighted in color! It sure would have been nice if you’d mentioned that in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>OK, I think I’ve got it. 
Your `Source: (?<group>.*/).*\n` regex is capturing, in the `group` group,
everything after the `Source:`  up through the last `/` on the line. 
So, for your example, it is capturing `/disk/media/Camera/`. 
To capture the JPEG image filename, you want</strike>

```
Source: .*/(?<group>.*)\n…
```

OK, here we go again. 
I believe that you *are* getting the static backreference that you want. 
The problem is that you aren’t getting the backreference
that you think you’re getting. 
I think your capture group (and subsequent backreference) is just `/`. 
I don’t understand why that would happen,
except to make a wild guess that the `.*` is operating in non-greedy mode,
so `.*/` captures everything up through the ***first*** `/`. 
Maybe the `?` is somehow being interpreted to mean that.

I guess what you want might be

```
Source: (?<group>.*/)[^/]*\n…
```

which forces the `.*/` to capture everything up through the *last* `/`.

Comment: Like I said in the question this is the folder that I want not the filename so my group is fine. My question is about "static" backreference.

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: @Scott I agree with your second analysis - it seems that `(?<group>.*/)` is capturing non-greedily in this context.

Comment: @steeldriver: That sounds like a bug to me (or, alternatively, bad documentation). What do you think?

Comment: @Scott it certainly appears inconsistent to me, but I'm not competent enough with PCRE to know whether that's the intended behavior or not

Comment: it works that way and effectively your explanation make sense, so my misundersting of the content of what the group was capturing, let me think that backreference was «dynamic» but it was never the case. I get it now and feel kind of stupid (like always when I got answer from SO). thanks